# Refresh hadoop count

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am receiving a quota limit error message when attempting to write to an hdfs directory:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.NSQuotaExceededException):
The NameSpace quota (directories and files) of directory /path/to/my/directory is exceeded:
quota=750000 file count=750001
```

After removing several files, I am still receiving the same count using

```
hdfs dfs -count -v -q /path/to/my/directory
```

**Questions**

- Does Hadoop need some time in order to synchronize its count metadata
  ?
- Is there any way to force it to do so ?

Comment: How did you "remove" files? If you used `hdfs dfs rm`, then the files are still in HDFS Trash directory

Comment: @OneCricketeer the trash doesn't count as a separate directory in this case ? The count of a directory takes into account the trash ?

Comment: For the namenode, quota, it is counted, since the file blocks are still being tracked